# Remove Module Lists in SugarCRM Custom Module

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

I want to remove the Modules Tab (module list and sub-module list) from my custom module.

I have tried some solutions but in vain. e-g:

```
options['show_header'] = false;
```

It removes all header but I want to remove Logo and Global Links.

Disable all modules and change `"tab=>false"` in `manifest.php` file of custom module.

Comment: What version/edition are you using?

Comment: I am using Sugar 6.5.14 CE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not an official way to do this through the configuration or anything, but you could use a custom logic hook for this to inject some javascript to hide the module list.

Say your custom module is abc_CustomModule, create a `logic_hooks.php` or add to it if it doesn't exist **custom/modules/abc_CustomModule/logic_hooks.php**

```
<?php

$hook_version = 1; 
$hook_array = Array(); 
$hook_array['after_ui_frame'] = Array(); 
$hook_array['after_ui_frame'][] = Array(1, 'Hide Modules', 'custom/modules/abc_CustomModule/abc_CustomModule_custom.php','abc_CustomModule_custom', 'hide_modules');
```

At the end of each page load for your custom module, it'll run the following code in **custom/modules/abc_CustomModule/abc_CustomModule_custom.php**

```
<?php

class abc_CustomModule_custom
{
    function hide_modules($bean, $event)
    {
        echo "<script>$('#ajaxHeader').hide()</script>";
    }
}
```

This simply outputs some javascript that will hide the div that contains the modules.

Comment: i was also looking to manage some other Div Tags in custom module like somewhere showing Actions only and somewhere hide them and show Recently Viewed. This will fix those problems too.
Thanks..